# How to bypass default tags in symfony services yml

Tags: symfony, yaml

Do you know if there is a way to avoid the _default tag for an abstract class into yml file?

```
  _defaults:
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

  My\Abstract\Class:
    abstract: true
    arguments:
      - '@.....'
      - '@....'

  Normal\Class:
    parent: My\Abstract\Class
    arguments:
      - '@...'
      - '@....'
```

Obviously I have many more Classes into yml file, I need to avoid the tag for only one abstract class.

Thank you.

Comment: Symfony version? Does trying to add a tag to an abstract class cause an error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
_defaults:
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

  My\Abstract\Class:
    abstract: true
    tags: [] # <------------ This line
    arguments:
      - '@.....'
      - '@....'

  Normal\Class:
    parent: My\Abstract\Class
    arguments:
      - '@...'
      - '@....'
```

Answer (score 0):

`_default` only works for the current yaml file. You can put your abstract class to an other yaml file so it does not inherit from the `_default` configuration.

If all your normal class share a common prefix, you can target the prefix instead of `_default` like

```
Namespace\Normal\:
    resource: '../src/Normal'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: Yes, it's an option. Is there a solution without moving my abstract class?

Comment: Did you try @Domagoj solution ?